# How can I create TeachingTip?

Tags: xaml, uwp, c++-cx

I am trying to add TeachingTip to Xaml file in a usual way:

```
<TeachingTip/>
```

But I get an error "The type 'TeachingTip' was not found".

I tried to add programmatically in cpp file (C++/CX):

```
TeachingTip^ tip = ref new TeachingTip();
```

The error is: "Identifier 'TeachingTip' is undefined".

All other controls work well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [TechingTip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.teachingtip) control is part of the [Windows UI Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/toolkits/winui/), not Windows. As such it resides in namespace `Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls` (as opposed to `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls`). To reference that control in XAML, you'll have to use the correct namespace. [Getting started with the Windows UI Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/toolkits/winui/getting-started) has detailed instructions.

The following XAML fragment should work:

```xml
<Page x:Class="..."
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:muxc="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"
      ...
      >

    <muxc:TeachingTip/>

    ...
</Page>
```

Likewise, when referencing the control in code, you'll have to specify the correct namespace.